# Saltstack host configuration and improving data readability

Tags: salt-stack

We're using salt (masterless, fwiw) to maintain a fleet of 10 hosts.  That will probably grow to 15-20 by year end.  I have a pillar file called `credentials/init.sls` that has a single huge hunk of yaml that looks something like this:

```
host_credentials:
  host1.example.com:
    role: staging
    mysql:
      superdatabase:
        role1:
          username: role1_username
          password: someSecretSHA1
          from_hosts:
            - host2.example.com
          grants: select, insert, update, delete
        role2:
          username: role2_username
          password: anotherSecretSHA1
          from_hosts:
            - host3.example.com
          grants: select

  host2.example.com:
    role: staging
    superthing:
      mysql:
        database: superdatabase
        host: host1.example.com
        role: role1
```

The point here is that the code that configures host1 can fetch all of its pertinent data from `host_credentials['host1.example.com']` and the code that sets up host2 can fetch its data from `host_credentials['host2.example.com']` with some lookups, for example, in host1's info in order to know the user and password for superdatabase on host1 with role1.

This works, but it's cumbersome.  In fact, it's sufficiently cumbersome that the firewall rules, which at first glance might also have been in this yaml structure, are now in a different pillar file.  Moreover, nothing controls that each host's yaml conforms to the pattern we want, so we have to do a fair bit of error checking in the salt code.

In addition, when someday we use a salt master, this would lead us to have to share all host information with all minions, hardly ideal.

The goal is to have each bit of information written down once.  If I change a password for a mysql database user, for example, I shouldn't have to change it twice, once on the server, again on each client that uses that database.  Moreover, I'd like to have semi-reasonable error messages when I do the wrong thing.  If I tell host4 to connect to mysql on host2, I should get an error message that says something like "host4 requested to connect to mysql on host2, but host2 does not run a mysql server".

At the moment, the only better solution I've found is to write some python code (using the salt py renderer) that generates an empty object but does a lot of checking in the middle.

`salt/codequal/init.sls`:

```
#!py

def run():
    # Do lots of error checking here.
    return {}
```

Any feedback most welcome.  Since I haven't seen this sort of thing written down, I suspect I've missed a more natural way to do what I want.

Comment: what do you mean by "this would lead us to have to share all host information with all minions, hardly ideal", why would it lead you to share all host information with all minions?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Maybe I'm wrong on that point.  Perhaps salt master aggressively trims the tree it sends to minions.  In which case the real question is just "are there better patterns for handling linked data in salt/jinja?"